# Lower Bound on Oscillatory Integral

Tags: fourier-analysis, asymptotics, harmonic-analysis, oscillatory-integral

Let $p,y\in\mathbb{R}^d\setminus\{0\},\beta>0$ be given and fixed and define for all $\alpha>0$, $$I(\alpha) := \int_{x\in\mathbb{R}^d}\exp(\mathrm{i}\alpha p\cdot x-\alpha\beta \|x-y\|^2)f(x)\mathrm{d}x$$ where $f:\mathbb{R}^d\to[0,1]$ is some bump function (smooth, non-negative, of compact support).

I am interested in estimating (or obtaining a lower bound) on $|I(\alpha)|$ for very large values of $\alpha$. In particular, to see that $|I(\alpha)|\geq g(\alpha)$ as $\alpha\to\infty$, for some simple $g$ which vanishes at infinity (say, Gaussian).

$I(\alpha)$ is essentially the Fourier transform of a bump function and a Gaussian evaluated very far away from the origin. So I tried to use the convolution theorem and the fact that the Fourier transform of a Gaussian is a Gaussian, but it's still not clear to me how this helps, because I don't know quantitative estimates on the Fourier transform of a bump function.

Then I came across: [this website](http://www.tricki.org/article/When_controlling_an_oscillatory_integral_bump_functions_and_bounded_phase_corrections_are_not_very_important) which claims that "When controlling an oscillatory integral, bump functions and bounded phase corrections are not very important". So I replaced $f$ with another Gaussian:

If we take as a model for $f$ the function $$ f(x) = \chi_{[-1,1]}(\|x\|)\exp\left(1-\frac{1}{1-\|x\|^2}\right)$$

then we replace it with some Gaussian $\tilde{f}(x) := \exp\left(-\delta \|x\|^2\right)$ where $\delta>0$ is some parameter to be adjusted later (say, $\delta=2$).

We then obtain \begin{align}I(\alpha)&=\int_{x\in\mathbb{R}^d}\exp(\mathrm{i}\alpha p\cdot x-\alpha\beta \|x-y\|^2-\delta \|x\|^2)\mathrm{d}x\\&=\exp(-\frac{\alpha\beta\delta}{\alpha\beta+\delta}\|y\|^2)\int_{x\in\mathbb{R}^d}\exp(\mathrm{i}\alpha p\cdot x-(\alpha\beta+\delta) \|x-\frac{\alpha\beta}{\alpha\beta+\delta}y\|^2)\mathrm{d}x\\&=\exp(-\frac{\alpha\beta\delta}{\alpha\beta+\delta}\|y\|^2)(\frac{\pi}{\alpha\beta+\delta})^{\frac{d}{2}}\exp\left(-\frac{\alpha^2}{4(\alpha\beta+\delta)}\|p\|^2+\mathrm{i}\alpha p \cdot y\right)\,.\end{align}

However, how do you estimate the error of replacing $f$ by a Gaussian?

We can do a similar exercise replacing $f$ by a Taylor approximation to its second degree, e.g..

Most of the texts I read about estimating oscillatory integrals deal with the case that the phase is rather complicated. However here it is just the Fourier transform, whose gradient never vanishes.

Comment: wow! big spender.  (i have done the same.  what's the point of getting some rep if you never spend it.)

Comment: It seems you want a function $g(\alpha)$ positive for large enough values of $\alpha$. Numerical evaluation suggests that $I(\alpha)$ can have infinite number of zeroes (tending to infinity of course). If it is true, such a function $g$ does not exists.

Comment: @Andrew, so if $f$ is a Gaussian $g$ is also a nice Gaussian, and deforming $f$ into a smooth function with compact support suddenly makes $I(\alpha)$ have infinitely many zeros infinitely far away?

Comment: @PPR sorry, I missed factor $\alpha$ at the norm. So it's not just a Fourier transform. And the said numerical calculations corresponds therefore to the case $\beta=0$. For $\beta>0$ calculations of the same example don't show zeroes.

Comment: @PPR can you be more precise about what you want $I(\alpha)$ to depend on? Do you want it to depend on $p,y,\beta$, or $f$?

Comment: @mathworker21, $p,y,\beta,f$ are fixed parameters, so of course $I(\alpha)$ depends on them. If you can find explicit formula which features $p,y,\beta,f$ great, but the main question is how things behave as $\alpha\to\infty$ for fixed $p,y,\beta,f$.

Comment: @PPR But then the answer depends on what $p,y,\beta,f$ are.  So can I give a lower bound for $I(\alpha)$ for one example of $p,y,\beta,f$?

Comment: @mathworker21, sure, take $f(x):=-\exp(1-\frac{1}{1-\|x\|^2})\chi_{(-1,1)}(\|x\|)$, $p=e_1$, $y=e_2$ and $\beta=1$.

Comment: @PPR last bargaining attempt: is there any example I can take with $d=1$?

Comment: What lower bound did you get by replacing $f$ with a Gaussian?

Comment: @mathworker21 actually I am not sure...

Comment: @AngelaRichardson see edit.

Comment: I think the following is true. If $\beta$ is large enough (other parameters fixed) and $f(y)\ne0$ then $|I(\alpha)|\ge C|f(y)|e^{-c\alpha}$, $\alpha>\alpha_0$. Function $f$ is required to be a bit smooth and vanishing fast enough at infinity, no need to be non negative and with compact support.

Comment: @Andrew that seems like a weird conjecture, due to the "if $\beta$ is large enough" part... The bound $|I(\alpha)| \ge C |f(y)|e^{-c\alpha}$ for large $\alpha$ is true or false for a particular $\beta$. So you're saying there is just some cutoff $\beta$ for which it switches from (absolutely) false to (absolutely) true? I don't think so...

Comment: As I've said for $\beta=0$ there seems to be an infinite number of zeroes. The same calculations indicate that for small $\beta>0$ it is also true. Though it's not a proof of course. Still those zeroes are regular enough and for large $\alpha$ it seems to be like $I(\alpha)\approx Ce^{-c\alpha} \cos(\omega \alpha+\varphi)$.

Comment: @Andrew yes, the fact that it fails for small $\beta$, together with my reasoning, suggests it fails for large $\beta$. but, let's just let the math gods adjudicate this debate.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example, not using bump functions admittedly, where $I(\alpha) \equiv 0$.

Taking $\beta = 1$ for simplicity, a slight modification of the Gaussian example included in the question shows that if we define $f_{z}(x) = e^{-\| x - z \|^{2}}$ for $z \in \mathbb{R}^{d}$, then
\begin{align}
I_{z}(\alpha)
&= \int_{\mathbb{R}^{d}} \exp(i \alpha p \cdot x - \alpha \| x - y \|^{2}) f_{z}(x) \, dx \\
&= \left( \frac{\pi}{\alpha + 1} \right)^{d/2}
\exp \left(
-\frac{\alpha^{2}}{4(\alpha + 1)} \| p \|^{2}
-\frac{\alpha}{\alpha + 1} \| y - z \|^{2}
\right)
e^{i \alpha p \cdot y}.
\end{align}

The key property that I want to focus on here is that if $z_1$ and $z_2$ are such that $\| y - z_1 \| = \| y - z_2 \|$, then $I_{z_1} \equiv I_{z_2}$.

So if we define $f(x) = f_{z_1}(x) - f_{z_2}(x)$ for such $z_1$ and $z_2$, the resulting oscillatory integral is identically zero.

This isn't a representative example, of course, but I would suspect that bounding $I(\alpha)$ away from $0$ as $\alpha \to \infty$ would be pretty hard in general.

The form of the integral is very similar to that of the FBI (Fourier–Bros–Iagolnitzer) transform, so the behavior of $I(\alpha)$ might depend on local properties of $f$ at $y$, and in the direction of $p$.

Comment: Hi Jason, thanks for this. However, shouldn't $f$ be positive?